# Merge two int array from one array without duplication

Tags: c, arrays, merge

I am trying to merge two arrays into one without duplication but my code does not work correctly. Can anyone suggest how to fix this problem?

```
void unify(int set_A[], int size_A, int set_B[], int size_B, int set_C[], int size_C)
{
  int i,j,count=0,indx=size_A;
  for(i=0;i<size_A;i++)
  {
    set_C[i]=set_A[i];
  }

  for(i=0;i<size_B;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<size_A;j++)
    {
      if (set_B[i]!=set_C[j])
        count++;
    }
    if (count==size_A){
      set_C[indx]=set_B[i];
      indx++;
    }
  }

}
```

Example:

```
a{3 7 13 8 11 1 4}
b{5 7 1 2 3}

a_b{3 7 13 8 11 1 4 5 0 0 0 0 0..}
```

Comment: Is the merged array set_C ?

Comment: yes, arrays a , b is given and the size of array_c is the sum of a, b

Comment: What are `M` and `N` in the `for` loop?

Comment: the "o" in array c is junk value but i don't care if there junk values

Comment: Where is M or N being declared?

Comment: M and N are #define number ( in my program 5,7)

Comment: Note the first nested loop. You iterate the values of set_B, while `i` can reach `size_A - 1`

Comment: I don't understand, should you be iterating the second `for` loop from `0` to `size_B` rather than `M+N`

Comment: i know, so long it will work i fine with this...

Comment: This looks like homework to me. The simplest answer will have a nested for loop. Each index in your for loop should correspond to an index in your array. When you compare the two arrays and a unique value is found simply add them.

Comment: thanks gays. i got it...(needed to initiize the count evret time).

Answer (score 1):

Could probably be optimized, or at least made pretty:

```
void unify(int set_A[], int size_A, int set_B[], int size_B, int set_C[], int size_C)
{
    int indexC, indexTemp;

    for(indexC = 0; indexC < size_A; indexC++)
        set_C[indexC] = set_A[indexC];

    for(int indexB = 0; indexB < size_B; indexB++)
    {
        for(indexTemp = 0; indexTemp < indexC; indexTemp++)
        {
            if(set_B[indexB] == set_C[indexTemp])
                break;
        }

        if(indexTemp == indexC)
            set_C[indexC++] = set_B[indexB];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
void unify(int set_A[], int size_A, int set_B[], int size_B, int set_C[], int size_C)
{
    int counterC = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_A && counterC < size_C; i++)
    {
        int discard = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (set_A[j] == set_A[i])
            {
                discard = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (discard) continue;
        set_C[counterC++] = set_A[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size_B && counterC < size_C; i++)
    {
        int discard = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (set_B[j] == set_B[i])
            {
                discard = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (discard) continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < counterC; j++)
        {
            if (set_C[j] == set_B[i])
            {
                discard = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (discard) continue;


        set_C[counterC++] = set_B[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some small correction to your code to make it work (Not tested). Pay attention to the comments.

```
void unify(int set_A[], int size_A, int set_B[], int size_B, int set_C[]) {
    int i, j, indx = size_A;

    // Add the value from A to C
    for(i = 0; i < size_A; i++) {
        set_C[i] = set_A[i];
    }

    // Iterate the values of B
    for(i = 0; i < size_B; i++) {
        int count = 0;

        // Find if A contains B[i]
        for(j = 0; j < size_A; j++) {
            if (set_A[j] != set_B[i])
                ++count;
        }

        // If A doesn't contain B[i], add B[i] to C and increase indx
        if (count == size_A) {
            set_C[indx] = set_B[i];
            ++indx;
        }
    }
}
```

Although I would replace the first nested loop with a function to tell me if an array contains some value, like this:

```
int contains(int arr[], int size, int val) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == val)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The first `for` loop won't work if `set_A` has duplicates. OP didn't mention it, but `set_A` might have duplicate keys as well.